# How to ping an IP address using groovy and echoing if its reachable or not

Tags: groovy, ip-address, ping

Hello I want to ping an IP address and echo if the address is reachable or not by using groovy.

I want the results to be something like this if its reachable:

*Sending ping request to 192.168.2.20
Host is reachable*

And like this if its not reachable:

*Sending Ping Request to 192.168.2.20
Host is not reachable*

Is there any simple way to ping in groovy? Any help would be great, thanks.

Comment: Please add the code you have tried and how it failed (e.g. errors,
stacktraces, logs, ...) so we can improve on it.

Comment: Actually i haven't tried any code yet because i have no clue what to try, im just checking if there is a simple way to ping in groovy